# Double Array: Out of Bounds

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that finds the average of the inputs of a 2D array:

This is what I have written:

```
public class AverageLength
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int sum = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int[][] foobar = new int[][]
    {
      {0, 5, 7},
      {3, 2, 4},
      {8, 7, 3},
      {1, 5, 3}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < foobar.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j <foobar[0].length; j++)
      {
        System.out.println(foobar[i][j]);
        sum = sum + foobar[i][j];
        w++;
      }
    } System.out.println("Average = " + sum/w);
  }
}
```

However, if I change the array lengths and try what follows:

```
    int[][] foobar = new int[][]
    {
      {0, 5, 7, 3},
      {3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 4},
      {8, 3},
      {1, 5, 1, 2, 3}
    };
```

it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at AverageLength.main(AverageLength.java:18)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
foobar[0].length
```

to

```
foobar[i].length
```

when your sub arrays lengths are different you should get corresponding length

for example

```
{0, 5, 7, 3},
{3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 4},
{8, 3},
```

in this case

`foobar[0].length` is 4 .so when you loop through 3rd sub array `{8, 3}`
    and when you try to access 2nd index [3rd element ] you get error

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

because there is no 2nd index.

and also in 2nd sub array `{3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 4},` value 8 and 4 will not print because you loop 4 times .

Answer (score 0):

When you check in your seccond for for array length you should use i not 0, because if you use 0 you will always get length of just first array.

```
for (int j = 0; j <foobar[i].length; j++)
```

Comment: @June Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `foobar[0].length` you are using the length of the **first inner array** for **every inner array**. Use `foobar[i].length` instead, which will calculate the *current* array's length.

By the way: Calculating averages of int arrays can be done java-internally since Java8. An example of how to use Java8's **streaming API** to solve this task:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AverageLength
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[][] foobar = new int[][]
    {
      {0, 5, 7},
      {3, 2, 4},
      {8, 7, 3},
      {1, 5, 3}
    };

    System.out.print("Average = ");
    System.out.println(

            // convert 2D array to stream of arrays
            Arrays.stream(foobar)

            // flatten 2D array to 1D array
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)

            // let java calculate the average
            .average()

            // get result
            .getAsDouble());
  }
}
```

Benefits:

- code is easier to understand
- your program is potentially much faster
- code can be easily changed to run in several threads (use `.parallel()`)